# How to specify size of color filter dynamically

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, automation, video-editing

I've been using the [following crossfade from Gyan](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/17504/23109) as part of my workflow for a while, as I've found it to look superior to [other crossfade solutions](https://superuser.com/a/1643589/323079) and easy to adapt for different inputs. However, I'm now trying to implement it in a Bash script for automation purposes, and I'm having trouble dynamically generating the resolution in the line `color=black:1384x1080`.

```
ffmpeg -i "$1" -i "$2" -i "$3" \
-movflags faststart \
-filter_complex \
"color=black:1384x1080:d=186.367[base]; \
[0:v]scale=-2:1080,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
[2:v]format=yuva420p,fade=in:st=0:d=2:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+((168)/TB)[v1]; \
[base][v0]overlay[tmp]; \
[tmp][v1]overlay,format=yuv420p[fv]; \
[1:a][2:a]acrossfade=d=2[fa]" \
-map [fv] -map [fa] -map -0:v:1 -c:v libx264 -c:a libopus -shortest "output.mp4"
```

In the below line I'm able to use `scale=-2:1080` to scale the input and preserve its aspect ratio, but using the same syntax with the `color` filter results in several errors saying pretty much the same thing:

> Unable to parse option value "-2x1080" as image size

Is there any way to automate this part of the script, or do I have no choice but to do it manually?

Comment: Do you want the color size to be the same as the first input? If yes, set color to any size, then use scale2ref filter.  See example at https://superuser.com/q/1342287/

Comment: @Gyan I want it to be the same as the rescaled first input (i.e -2:1080).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scale2ref filter can be used to scale an input with reference to another input.

Add scale2ref like this, and reset the SAR after the final overlay.

```
color=black:16x16:d=186.367[base]; \
[0:v]scale=-2:1080,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
[base][v0]scale2ref[base][v0]; \
[base][v0]overlay[tmp]; \
[tmp][v1]overlay,format=yuv420p,setsar=1[fv]; \
[1:a][2:a]acrossfade=d=2[fa]" \
```