# Side-by-side Comparison with scale2ref & hstack: Wrong Content Received as Output

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-filters

I have two videos (no other streams there) with a format of 1440x1080. The first video should be positioned left to the second (at the right), whilst the second must be rotated by 90° clockwise (intention is a side-by-side comparison of a sports movement, recorded from two different angles). I thought I had understood the `scale2ref`/`hstack` idea behind https://superuser.com/a/1342314, but apparently, I do not:

My attempts goes wrong with the following preliminary test:

```
ffmpeg -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i first.mkv -i second.mkv -filter_complex_script combine.script -map "[out]" -profile:v high -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 125M out.mp4
```

`combine.script` looks like this:

```
[1:v]transpose=dir=clock[rot];
[rot]split[rot1][rot2];
[rot1][0:v]scale2ref=iw:main_h[sec];
[sec]setsar=1,drawbox=c=black:t=fill[sec2];
[sec2][rot2]hstack[outtemp];
[outtemp]showinfo[out]
```

The filters look correct, as `showinfo` provides the following output on the console:

```
[Parsed_showinfo_6 @ 000002b8d70ea380] n:1420 pts:   7753 pts_time:7.753   
duration:      0 duration_time:0       fmt:yuv420p cl:unspecified 
sar:1/1 s:2520x1440 i:P iskey:0 type:? checksum:6E7F7B44 
plane_checksum:[3481517B 70563476 BFD1F544] mean:[55 129 126] stdev:[54.3 16.0 13.8]
```

Note that `s:2520x1440` is mentioned there, so `scale2ref` and `hstack` must have worked properly (`1440 + 1080 = 2520`) - and thus `[out]` must have a size of 2520x1440.
However, looking at `out.mp4`, I observe that

- the video format still is 1440x1080,
- the content is just the same as `first.mkv`.

Version of ffmpeg is `2023-11-15-git-78f55457c9-full_build`

What am I doing wrong? Why does `out.mp4` apparently not receive the output of the filtergraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've left the reference output in

```
[rot1][0:v]scale2ref=iw:main_h[sec];
```

unlabelled, so it has been sent to the first (here, only) output file.

If I've understood your need correctly, you want this:

```
[1:v]transpose=dir=clock[rot];
[rot][0:v]scale2ref=oh*mdar:ih[sec][pri];
[pri][sec]hstack[out]
```

Comment: Thanks, much better already (but only close ;) ). I don't get though, why leaving an output unlabelled means implicitly to enforce pushing it to the first output, which is even mapped.

The bad thing about your current suggestion is, though, that the video at the right hand side is downscaled to the height of the left one. I would be willing to accept some black bars (at top or bottom or both) on the left picture (background is: details on the right one matter). Is that feasible?

Comment: After some playing around I ended up with `[1:v]transpose=dir=clock[rot];
[rot]split[rot1][rot2];
[rot1][0:v]scale2ref=iw:main_h[sec][nil];
[nil]nullsink;
[sec]setsar=1,drawbox=c=black:t=fill[sec2];
[sec2][rot2]hstack[canvas];
[canvas][0:v]overlay=0:(main_h-overlay_h)/2[out]`. The `nullsink` thingy isn't ideal, but it serves my purpose.